# Save and load a game in Adobe Air for iOS

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe

I have an inquiry about adobe air for iOS.Ok, so I'm developing a game sort of like angry birds, every time you complete a level you go to the next one.But, it's not a manual save when you complete a level, it automatically saves it.What do I need to do so when I leave the app the level that I'm now on is the unlocked level, not the one before or the entire game restarts again?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save when the application exits, you can subscribe to the Event.EXITING event.

Example:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.EXITING, onExit);

private function onExit(e:Event):void
{
     trace("Save here.");
}
```

Then, you can use SharedObjects like this:

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myGame");
so.data['score'] = int(yourCurrentScore);
so.flush();
```

Or you can just save a local file.

Check this tutorial for more details:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/saving_state_air_apps.html

Comment: One thing I would add to this is that you don't have to wait until the app exits to save the level progress - you can do that as soon as the level is completed.

Comment: Last time I checked, the `EXITING` event is never fired on iOS devices. Instead, listen to the `SUSPENDED` event, which is fired every time the app goes into the background (i.e. if the user hits the home button, opens another app or has an incoming call), and use your save routine there.

Comment: Totally forgot, there's another issue with the background app support on iOS. Once your app is suspended you have got only a couple of seconds to execute your code before the OS completely pauses your app, should be plenty of time to save the current state, though.